# PHP script timeout in Log Analyzer

Tags: php, mysql, linux, logging

I have been trying to get Log Analyzer to work for longer than I care to admit.  I can't seem to get syslog messages to display in the Log Analyzer web-GUI, but this morning I got the following error:

"While reading the logstream, the php script timeout forced me to abort at this point. If you want to avoid this, please increase the LogAnalyzer script timeout in your config.php.  If the user system is installed, you can do that in Admin Center."

I was not getting this error on Friday; only "No syslog records found."  The timeout is set to 30 seconds in the config file, but I read that setting will get overwritten back to the default anyway.  The database grew to over 4GB over the weekend.  Does the the db size have anything to do with this?

It's pretty clear I am new to php and Log Analyzer, so any help with both would be greatly appreciated.  I can post config file settings if needed.

Comment: I think you might struggle to find a LogAnalyzer expert here and might need to find a more general form. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase time. 30 second may be not enough for parse large file. For example set 600 seconds.

Another case to increase timeout - edit following line in php.ini file

```
; Duration of time, in seconds for which to cache realpath information for a given
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
max_execution_time = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many records in the database, the script does not have enough time to process everything. I keep the last 14 days in the database, that's enough.

```
USE Syslog;
DELETE FROM Syslog.SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```